# Linux: how do i know the module that exports a device node?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

If a have a /dev device node and its major/minor numbers how do i know the kernel module name that exported this node?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Short answer :

```
cd /sys/dev/char/major:minor/device/driver/
ls -al | grep module
```

Each device is generally associated with a driver, and this is all what the "device model" is about. The `sysfs` filesystem contains a representation of this devices and their associated driver. Unfortuantely, it seems not all sysfs have a representation of the device nodes, so this applyd only if your /sys directory contains a /dev directory.
Let's take an example, with `/dev/video0`

On my board, `ls -al /dev/video0` output is

```
crw-------    1 root     root      81,   0 Jan  1 00:00 video0
```

So major number is 81 and minor number is 0.
Let's dive into sysfs :

```
# cd /sys
# ls
block     class     devices   fs        module
bus       dev       firmware  kernel
```

The `sys/dev` directory contains entry for the char and block devices of the system :

```
# cd dev
# cd char
# ls
10:61  13:64  1:3    1:8    249:0  252:0  29:0   4:65   81:0   89:1
10:62  1:1    1:5    1:9    250:0  253:0  29:1   5:0    81:2
10:63  1:11   1:7    248:0  251:0  254:0  4:64   5:1    81:3
```

What the hell are this links with strange names ? 
Remember the major and minor number, 81 and 0 ?
Let's follow this link :

```
#cd major:minor (ie 81:0)
#ls -al
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root            0 Jan  1 01:56 .
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root            0 Jan  1 01:56 ..
-r--r--r--    1 root     root         4096 Jan  1 01:56 dev
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            0 Jan  1 01:56 device -> ../../../vpfe-capture
-r--r--r--    1 root     root         4096 Jan  1 01:56 index
-r--r--r--    1 root     root         4096 Jan  1 01:56 name
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            0 Jan  1 01:56 subsystem -> ../../../../../class/video4linux
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         4096 Jan  1 01:56 uevent
```

Now we can see that this device nod, which is how the device is presented to userspace, is associated with a kernel device. This association is made through a link. If we follow this link, we end up in a directory, with a driver link. The name of the driver is usually the name of the module :

```
# ls -al
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root            0 Jan  1 01:56 .
drwxr-xr-x   25 root     root            0 Jan  1 00:00 ..
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            0 Jan  1 01:56 driver -> ../../../bus/platform/drivers/vpfe-capture
-r--r--r--    1 root     root         4096 Jan  1 01:56 modalias
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            0 Jan  1 01:56 subsystem -> ../../../bus/platform
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         4096 Jan  1 01:56 uevent
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root            0 Jan  1 01:56 video4linux
```

So here the name of the module is vpfe_capture

Answer (score 4):

The answer to this question is most likely different based on a number of factors. For example, if you're running udev, devfs, pre-devfs, etc.

If you're using Ubuntu (or another equally modern distro) the `udevadm` command might be what you want.

```
% udevadm info -q path -n /dev/cdrom
/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.1/host3/target3:0:0/3:0:0:0/block/sr0
```

So, my /dev/cdrom is provided by the `sr` driver, which resides in the `sr_mod` kernel module. I don't know of a command that takes `/dev/cdrom` as an argument and prints `sr_mod` as output.