# How to find device driver associated with a device file?

Tags: linux, filesystems, linux-device-driver

```
ls -l /dev
```

command lists the device files, and the associated information like major number, minor number.

```
cat proc/devices
```

command helps me to find the device name associated with a major number.

So for a node, I have found the major number, device name.

I understood how to **auto create** a device file, by populating the class information under /sys/class => By installing the device driver module, i can find the device file created.

I cant trace back from device file to the corresponding module.

In essence,how to find the Device driver/module associated with the device file, with these information?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linux: how do i know the module that exports a device node?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911050/linux-how-do-i-know-the-module-that-exports-a-device-node)